# GROUP_CONCAT for multiple columns

Tags: sqlite, group-concat

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE cities  
(
    `year` INTEGER,
    `job` TEXT,
    `well` TEXT
);

INSERT INTO cities (`year`, `job`, `well`)
VALUES ('2001', 'A', 'G1'),
       ('2001', 'S', 'G1'),
       ('2001', 'S', 'G2'),
       ('2002', 'S', 'G1'),
       ('2008', 'S', 'G2');

SELECT year, GROUP_CONCAT( job || '-' || well, ',  ') AS id_city
FROM cities
GROUP BY year;
```

I get:

```
year    id_city
--------------------------
2001    A-G1,  S-G1,  S-G2
2002    S-G1
2008    S-G2
```

I want:

```
year   job   well
---------------------
2001    A     G1
2001    S     G1,G2
2002    S     G1
2008    S     G2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should group by `job` also and use only `well` in `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT year, 
       job,
       GROUP_CONCAT(well, ', ') AS id_city 
FROM cities 
GROUP BY year, job;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/hxnJFIrY).